# Is there a free software addition to SQLite available for data-replication?

Tags: sqlite

I am aware of the possibility to create my own trigger(ed) solution, but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)'s [SQL API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/sql-160887.html) is completely SQLite compatible and offers [HA/replication](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/high-availability-099050.html) for high availability. The combination of SQLite's easy-of-use and Berkeley DB's scalability and reliability are a great combination.

Disclaimer: I'm the Product Manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm a little biased. However, one of the main benefits of adding the SQLite API to Berkeley DB is that SQLite applications can now have HA/replication for mission-critical, highly available applications.

Comment: I read from the docs: Only the master node can modify the database. So this is not for me :-(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are some:

- [LiteReplica](http://litereplica.io)  (Single master)
- [LiteSync](http://litesync.io)  (Multi-master)
- [AergoLite](https://aergolite.aergo.io)  (Blockchain based)

They are additions to the SQLite3 code. The interface is unchanged so we don't need to change the application code.

Disclosure: I am the creator